# How do I clear a log file that is currently in use?

Tags: log, logging

I'm trying to clear a log file in use, and all the commands I've tried so far:

```
truncate
less
tail
filename
```

Don't get the job done. Deleting the file and creating a new file with the same name doesn't work either.

I heard about a config-file for the log but I have no idea where this is kept. Is there ANY way to fix this problem? This log file will get so big it'll crash my system.

Comment: Which log file, and what was the error message?

Answer (score 4):

Are there many methods how clear/delete log files. Some of log you can delete, some not and some you can truncate.

For linux system log (such as mail.log for example) I use this method. Steps 1 and 2 are optional, but sometines you need check older logs and backup is sometimes useful. ;-)

1. Optional: Copy log file

   ```
   cp file.log file.log.old
   ```
2. Optional: Use Gzip on copy of log

   ```
   gzip file.log.old
   ```
3. Use `/dev/null` for clean file

   ```
   cat /dev/null > file.log
   ```

Comment: Simply `> file.log` should be enough. No need for `cat /dev/null`.